# vscode 上のデバッグ機能を、開発用 goapp のサーバーに対して実行できますか？

Tags: go, google-app-engine, vscode

vscode の go plugin を用いて設定を素直に行うと、普通の go プログラムに関しては、 vscode 上のデバッグ機能(ブレークポイント・ステップ実行)が利用できます。

今、 goapp serve で起動するローカルの DevServer に対して、同じようにデバッグ実行したい、と考えました。

これは、実現可能でしょうか。実現できる場合、どのような設定を行うべきでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve)をリモートマシン、開発サーバー両方にインストールし、
`launch.json`の`host`を開発サーバーのIPアドレスに書き替え、開発サーバー上で、`delve`を手動実行してからデバッグを開始すれば良さそうです。

Qiitaにこの説明をした[エントリー](https://qiita.com/momotaro98/items/7fbcad57a9d8488fe999)がありました。
英語ですがGoappでもほぼ同様の[説明](https://medium.com/average-coder/how-to-debug-a-running-go-app-with-vscode-76e3eac45bd)がありました

*この回答は、`google`で`vscode` `go` `リモートデバッグ`をキーに検索を掛けて発見しました。*